# how to sync live data from database in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm creating a online grocery shopping with flutter so I need to integrate live data update without refresh like Fetch api data automatically syncing how to achieve this feature I have already created the app and now I have to add this feature i'm using `getbuilder` in flutter is there any way to add realtime sync to `getbuilder`

Comment: i need sync feature for this page [link] https://gist.github.com/crazymhegde/c2e650370e05ea065c49cbaad8008092

Comment: I would use GraphQL subscriptions for this. Any update in your database should send the notification out (by db trigger perhaps). You route this message through GraphQL as a mutation, and have your device subscribe to mutation changes.

Comment: You can use Streams for this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.